# How do I keep theTD headers active after filtering the table with javascript

Tags: javascript

I use the following script to filter the table on users input. After the user types the table starts filtering rows. The input is saved so when a page refresh/reloads occurs the rows the user filtered stay active. After the refresh the table header is disapeared and only the filtered rows are showing. Does anyone has any idea how to keep the table header active after filtering the table?

This is the part of the code;

```
      <table class="userprof" align='left'>
        <tr>
          <td class="footer">Filter:
            <input type="text" id="myInput" name="filter" style = "color:black !important;" onkeyup='saveValue(this);' placeholder="Filter table...">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </p><br /><br /><br />
        
    
        
    </head>
    
    
        <table width="99%" id="myTable" class="sortable" >
        <tr>
     
        <td class="header" style="padding: 1px;">Name</td>
        <td class="header">Email</td>
        <td class="header">Edit</td></tr>
     
     
    <?  //Selecteer accounts.
      
    
      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE purpose= ?");
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $status);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->get_result(); 
    }
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    
       <tr>
        <td style="color:<?= htmlspecialchars($cat_color) ?> ", class="footer"><?= htmlspecialchars($row['name']) ?></td>
        
    
        <td style="color:<?= htmlspecialchars($cat_color) ?> ", class="footer"><?= htmlspecialchars($row['email']) ?></td>
      
        
        <td class="footer" width="1px"><input type="button" value="Edit" id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']); ?>" onClick="this.style.color='gold';"
        class="submit edit_data" /></td>
      
       
        </form>
        </tr>
        
        
        <? } ?>
        </table><div id="bottom"></div>
    
<script>

// Store the input in a variable for reference.
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
var savedValue = getSavedValue("myInput");

// Immediately filter the table and set the input value.
filterTable(savedValue);
myInput.value = savedValue;

//Save the value function - save it to localStorage as (ID, VALUE)
function saveValue(e) {
  var id = e.id; // get the sender's id to save it . 
  var val = e.value; // get the value. 
  localStorage.setItem(id, val); // Every time user writing something, the localStorage's value will override . 
}

//get the saved value function - return the value of "v" from localStorage. 
function getSavedValue(v) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
    return ""; // You can change this to your default value. 
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(v);
}

function filterTable(value) {
  console.log(value);
  var filter = value.toUpperCase();
  var rows = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody").rows;

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var nameCol = rows[i].cells[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rankCol = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var rankerCol = rows[i].cells[5].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var typeCol = rows[i].cells[6].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var emailCol = rows[i].cells[3].textContent.toUpperCase();
    var ownerCol = rows[i].cells[8].textContent.toUpperCase();
    if (nameCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || rankCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || ownerCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || rankerCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || typeCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 || emailCol.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      rows[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

myInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
 console.log(event); // Check if the event is fired.
 var value = event.target.value;
 saveValue(event);
 filterTable(value);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty simple as it seems.

I changed this:

```
<table width="99%" id="myTable" class="sortable" >
        <tr>
     
        <td class="header" style="padding: 1px;">Name</td>
        <td class="header">Email</td>
        <td class="header">Edit</td></tr>
```

To this:

```
<table width="99%" id="myTable" class="sortable" >
        
     
        <thead><td class="header" style="padding: 1px;">Name</td>
        <td class="header">Email</td>
        <td class="header">Edit</td></thead>
```

And my problem is solved. Thanks for reading, sorry for the seemingly easy question.